# Calling memset causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, unix, struct, segmentation-fault, memset

This program causes a seg fault on my UNIX machine. I narrowed the cause down to the **second** call of memset().

Why is this behaviour occurring? The first "chunk" of code is almost the same as the second, isn't it? Why didn't the **first** call of memset segfault if the second one does?

I looked over other threads concerning segfaulting memset calls, but none of them were similar to this.

In case you were wondering why I wrote such a trivial program, it's adapted from another program I've been writing that I was using to teach myself how to apply memcpy() to structures.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    int x;
    char text;
} FilesStruct;

int
main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    FilesStruct *old_dir;
    memset(old_dir,0,sizeof(FilesStruct));
    old_dir->x = 3;
    old_dir->text = 'c';
    printf("old dir: %d,%c\n",old_dir->x,old_dir->text);

    FilesStruct *new_dir;
    memset(new_dir,0,sizeof(FilesStruct));
    new_dir->x = 7;
    new_dir->text = 'g';
    printf("new dir: %d,%c\n",new_dir->x,new_dir->text);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
FilesStruct *old_dir;
memset(old_dir,0,sizeof(FilesStruct));
```

attempts to write to an uninitialised pointer.  This results in undefined behaviour, including possibly a crash.  Its just luck (good or bad, depending on how you look at it) that the first instance of this behaviour didn't crash.

You need to allocate memory for `old_dir`.  The easiest way to do this is to declare it on the stack

```
FilesStruct old_dir;
memset(&old_dir,0,sizeof(old_dir));
```

or you could dynamically allocate on the heap (making sure to call `free` when you no longer need the object)

```
FilesStruct *old_dir = calloc(1, sizeof(*old_dir);
/* use old_dir */
free(old_dir);
```

The same applies to `new_dir` further down your code.

Comment: Oh, I was intending to use memset as an initialiser, guess I got that quite wrong.

So my declaration only declares a pointer, but not the underlying structure; hence, I need to allocate memory before memsetting to 0?

Comment: @Noob Yes, that's it exactly

Answer (score 3):

Neither `old_dir` nor `new_dir` are initialized,  so this is undefined behavior. One solution would be to allocate both variables on the stack:

```
FilesStruct old_dir;
//...
FilesStruct new_dir;
```

and use the `&` operator to obtain the address when calling `memset`:

```
memset(&old_dir,0,sizeof(FilesStruct));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
FilesStruct *old_dir;
```

This defines a FilesStruct pointer. It is uninitialized, so it doesn't actually point to any storage for a FilesStruct.

```
memset(old_dir,0,sizeof(FilesStruct));
```

Will tell memset to zero out whatever old_dir points at, but as the pointer is uninitialized, you get undefined behavior.

You'll need to provide storage for your pointer, e.g.

```
FilesStruct *old_dir = malloc(sizeof(FilesStruct));
```

In your case you don't really need a pointer or dynamically allocated memory, you might do

```
FilesStruct old_dir;
memset(&old_dir,0,sizeof(FilesStruct));
old_dir.x = 3;
old_dir.text = 'c';
printf("old dir: %d,%c\n",old_dir.x,old_dir.text);
```